# Assigning text from a textfield to a managed object context with Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Need help getting the save function to work, Im new to CoreData and im just following along with a treehouse course but either the treehouse course was using a previous version of xcode or a different version of swift because when i followed along it gave me an error.

the error says "value of type 'item' has no member 'text'"

```
class popUpViewController: UIViewController {


    let managedObjectContext = CoreDataStack().managedObjectContext

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
    @IBOutlet var keyField: UITextField!

     @IBAction func save(_ sender: Any) {


        guard let text = keyField.text, !text.isEmpty else { return }


        let item = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Item", into: managedObjectContext) as! Item

        item.text = text

    }
```

}

Comment: Please add more context ...

Comment: What error did you get? You're leaving out the most important detail.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this and let me know if it works :

```
 func setValuesToModel(){
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Item", in: context)
    let item = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
    item.setValue("text You want", forKeyPath: "text")
    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        print("Could not save. \(error) , \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Comment: **REPLACE** "text You want" with text.(Your variable)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a func like below and just pass the text you want to store. Update key and entity name base on your requirements

```
 func save(text: String) {

    // 1 fetching item and updating with text 
    let item = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Item", in: managedObjectContext)!

    item.text = text  // if you have created model class use this or user below line
    // item.setValue("Sample Text", forKeyPath: "text") //key will be the attribute name you have created 

    // 2 saving part
    do {
        //save tour context after setting value
        try managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```